# calling python script from ajax got: malformed header from script. Bad header

Tags: python, jquery

I am writting a application using jquery(ajax) and python. When I send the request using ajax to call a php script, everything works. But when I tried to call a python script, I got this error.

malformed header from script. Bad header=AAAAAA

I am not sure what I am missing. The only difference is the type of script ajax is calling.

Following is my php script called:

```
*<?php
  echo "AAAAA"
?>*
```

Following is my python script called:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "AAAAAA"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

===========================================
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you really emitting `*` from your PHP?  Technically anything outside of the `<?php ?>` is going to be sent to the client.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=cgi+tutorial

Comment: Also, what happens when you change `print` to `sys.stdout.write()` in your Python?

Answer (score 17):

PHP was designed for web programming so it automatically attaches `Content-type` to HTTP headers but Python doesn't. Prepend this to `main()`:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
```

Comment: I was having great trouble with getting the Hello World example from the Python docs to work. The problem turned out to be that I wasn't putting in the line return after the "content-type" declaration.